# Index in ngFor is not unique

Tags: angular, ionic4

Hello I have basic toggle/hide function for displaying/hiding the content once user click on it. On first click it loads data from API. However sometimes indexes are the same so 2 elements are opening instead of one.

Simplified html

```html
<div *ngFor="let children of day.filteredChildren$ | async; let j = index">
<div class="child-dayreport" *ngIf="children.hasDayreport == 1">
                    <button class="btn-show-report"
                      (click)="toggleReportVisibility(children.id, selectedDateTitle, j)">{{childrenAll[j].reportExpanded ? 'Verstecke Tagesrapport' : 'Zeige Tagesrapport'}}</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="child-dayreport" *ngIf="children.hasDayreport > 1">
                    <button class="btn-show-report"
                      (click)="toggleReportVisibility(children.id, selectedDateTitle, j)">{{childrenAll[j].reportExpanded ? 'Verstecke Tagesrapport' : 'Zeige Tagesrapport'}}</button>
                  </div>
<div>
```

click handler

```js
toggleReportVisibility(id, date, index) {
    console.log('toggleReportVisibility', id, date, index)
    this.childrenAll[index].reportExpanded = !this.childrenAll[index].reportExpanded;

    const currentChild: any = this.childrenAll.filter(child => child.id === id);
    if (currentChild[0].reports.length === 0 && currentChild[0].hasDayreport !== 0) {
      this.getChildrenDailyReport(id, date)
        .then(() => this.childrenAll[index].reports = this.report)

    }
  }
```

@EDIT I tried to add trackBy function like that, but It didn't work.

```html
<div *ngFor="let children of day.filteredChildren$ | async; index as j; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

```js
trackByFn(i: number) {
    return i;
}
```

Comment: "Indexes are the same", are you sure about that? You really mean "index" or `id`? Did you try displaying the indexes in the view to see if there are duplicates?

Comment: Unfortunately the indexes were unique however entire html file is so large and complicated and I didn't find out that this loop is inside of another loop. So using the helper counter variable instead of index from ngFor is right solution. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the HTML file precisely, which is huge... And this loop was part of another loop, so the *ngFor indexes were correct. Creating independent counter `children.counter` variable, which is always unique.

```html
<button class="btn-show-report"
(click)="toggleReportVisibility(children.id, selectedDateTitle, children.counter)">{{childrenAll[children.counter].reportExpanded ? 'Verstecke Tagesrapport' : 'Zeige Tagesrapport'}}</button>
```